# Прямые под 45 градусов

Tags: c++

Не могу найти ошибку в своём коде. Задача со степика. Не проходит 3 тест.

> Напишите программу, при выполнении которой с клавиатуры считываются координаты точки на плоскости (x, y - действительные числа) и определяется принадлежность этой точки заданной заштрихованной области (включая границы). В случае, если точка внутри заштрихованной области -- выведите слово "Inside", если снаружи - "Outside".
>
> [image]

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    bool a = (y <= 3) && (y >= -x - 4) && (x <= 3);
    bool b = (y <= 1) && (y >= -x - 2) && (x <= 1);
    if (a && !b) {
        cout << "Inside";
    } else {
        cout << "Outside";
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Вы умеете определить что точка внутри белого треугольника?

Comment: Умею, но по условию задачи  внутренний треугольник высечен @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, так в переменной b лежит.

Comment: @Qwertiy благодарю

Comment: Какая связь между заголовком и вопросом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В переменной `b` лежит принадлежность токи внутреннему треугольнику с его границей, а надо без границы. Поменяй нестрогие неравенства на строгие.

PS: И не надо лишние скобки ставить - тут не паскаль.